# HTML5 Canvas - Wireframe Sphere in 2d

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking to draw a 3D wire frame sphere in 2D Canvas. I'm not a math ninja by any means, so I'm wondering if anyone knows a simple way to draw one in Canvas using lineto arc connections and drawing it with :math:

I would appreciate any assistance.

Something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sphere_wireframe_10deg_6r.svg

I'm hoping this is a simple equation, but if you know that it isn't (i.e. drawing that would be a lot of code), I would appreciate knowing that as well as I may need to reconsider what I wanna do.

Comment: Does it need to be a 2D canvas? I can't think of a way off the top of my head to draw that using lineto arc since you'd need to do a matrix multiply in order to rotate the circle about the Y axis. Would be really easy to accomplish with a 3D canvas context.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard given a) a function to convert from spherical coordinates to XYZ and b) a function to perform a projection from XYZ into 2D. Both of these exist on the Web.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread, but I had the same question and could not find any existing satisfying answer. That is, an answer other than "use WebGL" or "use Three.js". Lo and behold, I am the bearer of **great news**: it is actually possible to render such a sphere using exclusively Canvas2D's [`ellipse` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse), giving us:

- a straightforward implementation (~130 lines everything included)
- no need for computing vertices and edges
- sexy smooth edges

[image]

You can find [a demo on JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/yifayiq), for posterity, with a bunch of options.

The key is to notice that the "wireframe" we're trying to draw is solely composed of circles, and every circle rotated in 3d space will get projected to the camera as an ellipse. The question, then, is: how to find the ellipse corresponding to the projection of the rotated circle?

As we are only interested in circles that *lay on the surface of the sphere*, we can characterize each of them by the (inter)section of a plane and the (unit) sphere. Therefore, each circle can be described by a normal vector and an offset `-1 < o < 1`.

Then it's not too difficult to compute and draw the ellipse resulting from the projection of the circle:

```js
function draw_section(n, o = 0) {
  let {x, y, z} = project(_p, n) // project normal on camera
  let a  = atan2(y, x)           // angle of projected normal -> angle of ellipse
  let ry = sqrt(1 - o * o)       // radius of section -> y-radius of ellipse
  let rx = ry * abs(z)           // x-radius of ellipse
  let W  = sqrt(x * x + y * y)
  let sa = acos(clamp(-1, 1, o * (1 / W - W) / rx || 0)) // ellipse start angle
  let sb = z > 0 ? 2 * PI - sa : - sa                    // ellipse end angle

  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.ellipse(x * o * RADIUS, y * o * RADIUS, rx * RADIUS, ry * RADIUS, a, sa, sb, z <= 0)
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

The disks from your example image can be obtained by:

- rotating a plane around the z axis
- shifting a plane along the z axis

```js
function draw_arcs() {
  for (let i = 10; i--;) {
    let a = i / 10 * Math.PI
    draw_section(vec.set(_n, cos(a), sin(a), 0))
  }

  for (let i = 9; i--;) {
    let a = (i + 1) / 10 * Math.PI
    draw_section(Z, cos(a))
  }
}
```

A nice benefit of this method is that you can do this "shifting a plane along the Z axis" for all axes, resulting in a lovely wireframe that would be hard to reproduce if computing vertices and edges by hand:

[image]

The only change was the following:

```js
function draw_arcs() {
  for (let i = 9; i--;) {
    let a = (i + 1) / 10 * Math.PI
    draw_section(Z, cos(a))
    draw_section(X, cos(a))
    draw_section(Y, cos(a))
  }
}
```

The function `draw_section` above was carefully crafted so that it only draws the *camera-facing* arc of a given section, which means **we get occlusion-culling for free**.

[image]

(and my dirty trick to render the back of the sphere with a different color is to run `draw_arcs` again after flipping the canvas)

It's also possible to use 2 radial gradients to have some fake depth shading like in your image:

[image]

Sadly browsers seem to struggle a lot when drawing paths with gradients.

---

There are but two drawbacks I see right now:

- performance may vary between browsers. It's likely some optimization could be done, like merging successive calls to `.stroke()` into one. Frankly quite surprised by how slow using `ellipse` seems to be at times.
- it's a parallel projection rather than a perspective one. If we were to add perspective, projected circles would still appear as ellipses, but the calculation of the ellipse would be a tad more involved. I haven't done it yet, I expect it to be possible, might update my answer if I succeed.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest for you would probably to view the source of the SVG file ([here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Sphere_wireframe_10deg_6r.svg)) and recreate those paths using canvas commands.

If you want an actual 3d sphere, projected onto 2d space, I'd suggest using a library like Three.js

You can also look at some of the math I've done here: [swarms](http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/hNaYu/103/)
The _3d and Matrix modules should be all that you need.

Comment: Holy crap, @david that is an incredible canvas fiddle. Probably the most impressive fiddle I've seen recently. It even runs (somewhat slowly which is a given, but it works!) on my iPad. Do you have a website?

Answer (score 2):

This time SO didn't help me, so I've helped myself and here it is: a pure HTML5 + JavaScript configurable rendering or a wireframe sphere.

I started from this [excellent post](http://www.bitstorm.it/blog/en/2011/05/3d-sphere-html5-canvas/) and then went on. Basically I collected some vertex generation code from Qt3D and adapted to JS.

I'm not 100% sure the rotation functions are correct, but you are welcome to contribute back in case you find errors.

To be clearer, I've distinguished Z positions and draw white on the front and gray on the back.

Here's the result (16 rings x 32 slices) and related [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajehLusz/2/)

```
Enjoy
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aJMBp/

you should just draw a lot of these lines to create a complete sphere. This is a good starting point, give me 5 minutes and I'll see if I can improve it to draw a sphere.

Getting better:
http://jsfiddle.net/aJMBp/1/

Ok, thats def out of my capacity. However, another little improvement here: http://jsfiddle.net/aJMBp/2/

Comment: yeah, working on this but I mostly suck in the math part of it! I hope someone who knows 3d math better than us can take this drawing core and write the loop. I'm trying this right now however...

Comment: This might be the way to go, it's just that the curve of a sphere isn't a parabola. So just using the quadratic curve won't get you anywhere.